# Is there a way to convert Date format from date.toLocaleString() to UTC format?

Tags: javascript, angular, date, locale

I could find ways to convert the UTC format date to locale format,
example,

```
localeDate = date.toLocaleString() ==> "14/11/2020, 12:00:00 AM"
```

But is there a functionality the other way from localeString to UTC format. Whatever the locale the browser is configured with, based on that format it should convert back to UTC format like,

```
Utitiy_for_conversion(localeDate) ==> 2017-11-14T01:00:00.000Z
```

The utility should convert to UTC format time by fetching the format of date from locale settings that are configured in the browser

Comment: How about `date.toUTCString()`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @Pointy it works well with en-US locale, but not universal, as it throws "Invalid Date" for dd/mm/yyy format ex: "22/07/2020, 8:54:09"

Comment: That is a completely different problem; you're feeding the Date constructor an invalid string.

Comment: how should I resolve it, because a similar date format "08/07/2020, 7:28:32" doesn't throw any error, but in turn it is converted as "Fri, 07 Aug 2020 01:58:32 GMT" but I was expecting "Wed, 08 Jul 2020 01:58:32 GMT". I'm using en-GB locale as default browser settings

Comment: Consider using a locale aware library like globalizejs to do the parsing.